# Cross Language Messaging

Tags: c#, java, jms, messaging

We use a java-focused tool that uses JMS both internally and to communicate with external java software. We now have to set up a new interface to a C# application. Our JMS provider provides a C# implementation that should work but I'm not entirely sure JMS is the way to go in this case. It would introduce a new vendor-specific dependency in a C# application both for the details of the implementation and the support of the client.

Some googling led me to STOMP which seems to be an established wire-level protocol supported by multiple JMS-capable message brokers (hornetq, activemq,...) but there appears to be a distinct lack of actual clients in C# (and java to some extent). Without delving too deep I'm also not entirely sure where the emphasis on "Text" comes into play? Does it not support binary objects?

Another solution could be AMQP which is another wire-level protocol but the 1.0 spec has not yet been released and we are weary of implementing the 4-year old 0.9.1 spec because it seems a lot has changed in 1.0.

What solution would be best for inter-language asynchronous messaging considering security, support, transactionality, standards compliancy, portability,... Note that soap with the proper WS-* is not an option for this particular interface.

**EDIT1**:
I have seen questions such as [Cross-platform, cross-language messaging system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258638/cross-platform-cross-language-messaging-system) but they seem to focus on a specific tool that works in multiple languages. I'm actually looking for a standards compliant protocol that is or can be implemented by multiple vendors.

Comment: No matter what you do you are going to introduce some vendor or messaging platform specific functionality.  You could use email instead as that is cross platform but it is SMTP specific.

Comment: Protocol-specific is not a problem as long as the protocol is a well established standard. If SMTP were only available from one specific vendor or differed from vendor to vendor, that would be a problem

Comment: JMS is an establish interface which requires you load the appropriate driver for the server you are using. You should be able to write your core code so the choice of server used can be configured without changes to your code.

Comment: In java yes, but not from .NET, we need an inter-language solution.

Comment: Can you wrap the driver(s) with your own interface which is generic so that only this component needs to be replaced?

Comment: In C#? Yes, this would similar to the abstraction layer suggested in one of the answers. However we have no background in C# so the other team would have to manage such an abstraction.

Comment: Is vendor neutrality/independence is important for a .NET/C# solution? ;)

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to abstract the C# client from the underlying specific notification protocol and let it work at the level of in-ports and out-ports where in-ports and out-ports are implemented with common interop adapters - a relational database, a web service, a xml file in specific folder.

It is your responsibility to provide adapters and a bridge between adapters and your messaging subsystem but there are clear benefits: the mutual obligation between enterprise environments is defined at very common level. You can even replace the messaging subsystem someday and retain all your in- and out-ports. In other words, the C# client wouldn't even notice that you replaced JMS with another messaging infrastructure because it still sends/receives the data from the same set of adapters.

Comment: We have no C# knowledge in our software team so we would be hardpressed to support our own adapters. Abstracting the actual messaging backend will always be part of the solution though the abstraction will have to be managed by the C# application team.

Comment: That's why I recommend a set of common adapters you are sure C# has no problem with. We maintain a similar solution, the only difference is that we use MSMQ as the messaging subsystem and the shell is written in C#. And the idea of common adapters works great, PHP and Java guys has no problems in writing to the relational database and providing their own web services based on WSDL specifications. That's why I believe the similar approach would work for you.

Comment: Yes but someone has to maintain the C#-java bridge meaning we must either read MSMQ, they must write to a JMS or we must find another protocol that does the trick (not webservices and definately not database/filesystem).

Comment: There are no interop bridges in our approach. For example, Java guys use a stored proc to create notifications in the in-port (database) and we provide the core of the system which reads the database and sends notifications to MSMQ. Thus, all external systems are not aware of the internals of the notification engine. The database/webservices/filesystem IS the protocol you are looking for. It's like: they -> inport (database/webservice) -> you -> JMS -> you -> output (database/webservice) -> they. They are only aware of common adapters, you provide the internal details of the infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but 
[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is an AMQP implementation and has bindings for C# and Java.

In order to prevent "a new vendor-specific dependency in a C# application" you might want to have a look at the [Messaging Component in the Spring.Net framework](http://springframework.net/docs/1.3.2/reference/html/messaging.html) as well as their [related AMQP for .Net](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-amqp) project. This allows you to have POCOs and business logic separated from the messaging middleware and infrastructure.

Comment: Because AMQP 1.0 has not yet been finalized, I'm not sure if this is the best option at this time?

Comment: The linked Message Component of Spring.Net features other MQs too (e.g. TIBCO EMS, Apache ActiveMQ/NMS).

Comment: This may be outside the scope of the original question but is spring as big a dependency in .NET as it is in java? Can you simply use the messaging component much like you would the JMS api without the entire java EE stack? Disclaimer: I have no background in C# nor in spring.

Comment: I only have limited background in Java but .Net Spring.net generally isn't invasive. Also spring has very few external dependencies (besides the .Net framework) and only needs those when you need that feature (e.g. nhibernate is only needed if Spring.Data.NHibernate is used).